# Build file bar (Message broker) using Ant?

Tags: jenkins, ant, devops, ibm-integration-bus

I am trying create BAR file using ANT by using the command:

```
mqsicreatebar -data F:\Code\Broker\workspace -b C:\iib-ci-rep\result.bar -a MY_APP_NAME -skipWSErrorCheck
```

If I use the above command in Command Line Window, it create bar file successful. However if I remove "-skipWSErrorCheck", it will show some error message like that

> "Problem 2: Resource - /TTHD_EVN/InsertLog.msgflow; Error message -
>   Class  "javaComput.InsertLog_JavaCompute" is not in a Java Compute
>   Node project refere nced by "TTHD_EVN"

But I only want to build my app "MY_APP_NAME", not for all projects in workplace, how can I do that ?

Moreover, if I use xml script for building by using Ant & Jenkins, I can't not get "BAR" file, although it returned "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" result. Do you know why ?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="project" default="run">
  <target name="run" description="">
    <property name="toolkit.home" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\IntegrationToolkit90" />
    <property name="ant.bars.basedir" value="C:\iib-ci-repo" />
    <property name="bar.name" value="${ant.bars.basedir}\result.bar" />
    <property name="workspace.dir" value="F:\Code\Broker\worksp" />
    <antcall target="build" />
  </target>
  <target name="build">
     <echo message="Building the Message Broker Project @ ${workspace.dir}" />
      <echo message="Output ${bar.name}" />
     <exec executable="${toolkit.home}\mqsicreatebar.exe" spawn="false">
        <!-- <arg value="-data" />
            <arg value="${workspace.dir}" /> -->
        <arg value="-b" />
            <arg value="${bar.name}" />
        <!-- List all the message flow projects -->
        <arg value="-a" />
            <arg value="MY_APP_NAME" />

        <arg value="-skipWSErrorCheck" />
             <arg value="" />          

     </exec>
  </target>
</project>
```

Comment: That exec is surely not right, -data is a required parameter of mqsicreatebar, so it won't work the way you have it in your question.

Comment: Oh, I forgot uncommend "-data" tag, It can export bar now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you don't add -skipWSErrorCheck, mqsicreatebar will check for errors in the workspace, it doesn't matter that you build only 1 app in the workspace.

I recommend, that you put only those projects (applications) in a single workspace which you want to build and deploy together.

Comment: How can I auto-create a new workspace for my project ? Because I auto get source folder of my project from SVN or GIT, and want to create bar file immediately

Comment: The mqsicreatebar command will actually auto-generate a basic workspace for you if you point it to an empty or non-existent directory, with just the listed applications in the command added to it.

If you have some extra settings to fill in to make it work though (such as referenced variables), then the auto-generated workspace won't quite be enough for you; you will have to do some prep work in addition to letting the workspace be auto-generated.